# Zedgraph labels disappears

Tags: c#, graph, zedgraph

I have made bar diagram with horizontal lines, it works fine, and a combobox where the users can change to a pie chart, with sort of work, when the user change to pie chart it works fine, but when change back from the pie chart to the bar chart, only the bars come, not the title, the x-asis tick, they axis tick nor the custom labels for the y axis.

I have search the net, and tried the following lines

```
myPane.YAxis.Scale.IsVisible=true;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.IsVisible=true;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = 30;
myPane.YAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = 9;

myPane.Legend.IsVisible = true;
```

but it only shows the bars there and nothing else. it works fine, if the bars diagram is made before, and without shift to the pie-chart

Comment: Did you try zg1.invalidate ? and zg1.AxisChange().. where zg1 is your ZedGraph Control? That will force zedgraph to refresh.

Comment: Yes     zgc.AxisChange();
   
   zgc.Invalidate(); This is always my last line, no diffrence.

Comment: Found a solution, finally.

Making a rectangle for prooper size

    RectangleF rc=new RectangleF();
   
    rc.X=0;
    rc.Y=0; 
    rc.Width=zgc.Width;
    rc.Height=zgc.Height;

Make a new graph rather than a new masterpane

    zgc.GraphPane=new GraphPane(rc,"title","x - axis","y-axis");

Link the new pane

   myPane=zgc.GraphPane;

That worked for me, now I get the corect size, and all values and ticks.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, finally.

Making a rectangle for prooper size

```
RectangleF rc=new RectangleF();

rc.X=0;
rc.Y=0; 
rc.Width=zgc.Width;
rc.Height=zgc.Height;
```

Make a new graph rather than a new masterpane

```
zgc.GraphPane=new GraphPane(rc,"title","x - axis","y-axis");
```

Link the new pane

```
myPane=zgc.GraphPane;
```

That worked for me, now I get the corect size, and all values and ticks.